# Sharepoint Cascading Dropdowns - Show Default Value from List B in List A

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, cascading-dropdown

I have a sharepoint list setup on SP2013, for employees to make reservations for a training session. There is also a linked list where count against each session is updated when someone books a session, which has been completed using Nintex Workflows. So in effect:

**List A Cols** 
*Staff Name - Session Details*

**List B Cols**
*Session Details - Session Booking Count*

What I am trying to do is have the Session Booking Count shown on Newform of List A if user selects a specific session, and to write a validation to show error if Count > 10.

I have tried to setup a cascading dropdown option using jquery, and this does show the count of each session, however default value is coming as "(none)". User has to click on the drop down and select the count figure manually.

Is there a way to change this so that by default the count is shown?

The sharepoint I use does not have SPD or Infopath.

Comment: Since capabilities can vary greatly between versions of SharePoint, please make sure to always tag your post with which version (`2010`, `2013`, etc.) of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: Thanks, added the version in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can check this similar post for a sample script:
[how to Display additional lookup columns in NewForm.aspx after selected indexchanged.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2190dbd-08d7-446a-b960-33b10767f4de/how-to-display-additional-lookup-columns-in-newformaspx-after-selected-indexchanged?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

1. Add two lookup columns to display the Session Name and the relative Session Booking Count in List A.
2. Add the custom code with a Script Editor web part on the NewForm.aspx page in List A.

And for the column validation:
[how to validate a column using jQuery.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5c2a162-0e3e-4241-b0c8-365da9fa4caf/how-to-validate-a-column-using-jquery?forum=sharepointgeneral)